# Javascript SOAP request cross domain

Tags: javascript, soap

I just wanted to see what options I have. I can't just use something like cURL as you will see below.

So, I am in system A which is like an online system where I can build a form (I do not have access to their server and files).  One thing this system allows me to do is add javascript.

So within system A, I need to call an API. The API is hosted somewhere else.  I am trying to make this call via javascript but I get a cross domain error.

Now if you are wondering why I dont just use PHP, it's all to do with policies.  System A is fully certified meaning its been pentested and is fully secure.  Same applies to the API which is being used.  If I use PHP, I will have to host the PHP file on our server (dont have access to their server) and our server is not certified.  The client will not allow this and to get our server certified is a long process.  So to summarise, I can't do anything outside of system A.

I have seen that I could potentially use jsonp, but this only works with GET?  Stupid question, how do I know if I need to make a POST or GET request?

Also, in my situation, who is responsible for allowing the cross domain request?  Would it be system A (the system I am in) or would it be the API?

Any advice appreciated

Comment: I am not sure your about web api but for cross domain you can use jsonp or cors of jquery.

http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/

Comment: So the cross domain policy would lie on the web API, not system A?

Comment: yes as i know you can enable disable it in webapi configuration but you can directly call the web api using jsonp as i know rather webapi enabled or not. and for post you need to surely enable cross domain on web api config.